# Google Sheet built-in function/custom function order of execution

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function

My question is about the order of execution between built-in functions and app script functions. There is a certain built-in function I need executed before the rest of the app script function(s) are executed.

**What it currently does**

1. Data is copied to the first range
2. Data is copied to the third range
3. Validation rule rejects data in third range because it doesn't match any data of second range (range is blank at this stage because built-in function hasn't executed)
4. Built-in Filter function executes which copies required data from first range into second range.

**What I want it to do:**

1. Data copied to first range
2. Built-in Filter function execute and copy required data from first range into second range
3. Copy data into third range
4. Validation rule accepts in third range because the built-in function has populated second range.

Is there a way to make this happen or is Google Sheets hard wired to execute app script functions before built-in functions?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was:

Spreadsheet.App.flush();